# Restart App Overlay after unlocking Phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, overlay, background-process

I have an Android application written in Java that uses an Overlay Service to display a search bubble similar to Facebook chat-heads or One notes Overlay.

The problem I'm facing is that on my new phone (Samsung) (Android 9) overlays get terminated after around 5 minutes of the lock screen. The OneNote Overlay visibly restarts. 
I tried to implement the same by checking if was terminated by the system, not the user.
I also found a Broadcast Receiver that calls a function when the phone is unlocked even when my application is in the background.

Here I get the following error:

```
Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.[...]/.[...] }: app is in background
```

What can I do to go around that?

Do I have to "push" my app to the foreground, start the overlay, and move it back in the background? is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Android 10. (Not sure though). In Android 10 there's a new restriction that prevents you from starting an activity from a background service. More information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: No I'm Using Android 9 and as I stated, the OneNote App restarts from the Background. There must be a way.

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of battery saver enabled or your device closes the app for the need of memory?

Comment: the App itself is not terminated. it is still running in the background. Only the Overlay is getting terminated and the onDestroy method is called on the Service